# How to set permanent default applications on El Capitan

Tags: macos, defaults

Every time I restart my mac book pro, all my settings of default applications change to factory default applications. For eg, I set adobe acrobat reader DC as my default PDF viewer, sublime text as default text editor and google chrome as default browser but on next restart/power on, the default applications change back to preview, textedit and safari.

How can I make my changes permanent and prevent this change from happening?

Right now, for setting default apps, I right click on file -> Get Info -> Open With -> Change All
But this has to be done on every power on/restart.

Answer (score 1):

Never face this, but I would say to delete the 
/users//library/preferences/com.apple.launchservices.plist file
where  is your username

Then, define a preferred app for your PDFs, shutdown, restart and check

Comment: I do not have a com.apple.launchservices.plist file

Comment: Do not go in the Library of your "Macintosh HD", but in the Library of our account (the little house on the left pane when you double click on your hard drive icon)

Comment: See http://imgur.com/7fZAT8F ; sorry my OS is French.

Comment: I did go to the one in my account. Still couldnt find it there Philippe

Comment: Strange; http://imgur.com/XC4GWFh; 1st time I hear that OS X get rid off this file ??

Comment: So perhaps that we have to go the "hard way" with the Terminal ? https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/rebuild-launchservices-fix-duplicate-entries-os-xs-open-menu/

Comment: ...or the 'soft' way with [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html) - Maintenance > Rebuilding; check the top option, LaunchServices, uncheck everything else for now, hit Execute.

Comment: I have following 2 files: `com.apple.launchservices.secure.plist` and          `com.apple.launchservices.secure.plistcom.apple.LaunchServices.plist`